# Numbering Appendices After Bibliography in Backmatter

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, appendices

My graduate school requires the appendices to be after the bibliography but still numbered A,B,C, etc.  I'm running into a problem because I am using `\backmatter` before calling the bibliography but this turns off chapter numbering so then all appendices are numbered as .1 and so forth.  For example, I'd like to do the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{foo}
\section{Donald}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{bibstyle}
\bibliography{exampleBiB}

\appendix
\chapter{bar}
\section{Mickey}

\end{document}
```

and have the Mickey section labeled A.1.  I know that backmatter turns off chapter numbering so I realize this is the problem, but without it then the bibliography is incorrect.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it should be possible to just omit `\backmatter`.  unless the bibliography style and file are anomalous, the `.bbl` file probably begins with `\begin{thebibliography}`, and that, in turn, probably uses `\chapter*`, so the output shouldn't depend on a chapter number.  then `\appendix` will still be able to reset the chapter number to start at 1 (or A) to give the desired output.

Comment: Thanks! That worked beautifully. I was assuming the formatting of the bibliography depended on the \backmatter declaration.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Also, if you enter that as an answer, I could mark as solved. I'll do so myself at a later point, but wanted you to get the credit you deserve!

Answer (score 3):

it should be possible to just omit \backmatter.

unless the bibliography style and file are anomalous, the .bbl file probably begins with \begin{thebibliography}, and that, in turn, probably uses \chapter*, so the output shouldn't depend on a chapter number. then \appendix will still be able to reset the chapter number to start at 1 (or A) to give the desired output.